# What is the origin of "dirty money"?

Tags: etymology, money

On Wikipedia we read:

> **dirty money**: (idiomatic) Money that is illegally gained, illegally
>   transferred or illegally utilized. Especially money gained through
>   forgery, bribery, or thievery.

Is there a precise origin of the idiom "dirty money"? Why has the word "dirty" replaced "illegal"? (perhaps because an author has used it an important novel?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OED specifically traces the term "*dirty money*" to a source over a century old:

> **dirty money** (n.)
>   ***1897***   S. Webb & B. Webb Industr. Democracy I. 313   *When any class of work involves special unpleasantness or injury to clothing,
>   ‘black money’ or ‘dirty money’ is sometimes stipulated for*.
>   ***1960***   Sunday Express 14 Aug. 1/1,   *1,100 dockers‥are claiming ‘dirty money’ for handling a cargo of red oxide*.

Yet for some time, *dirty* has been applied to more than our dirty socks, or a muddy shirt.  *Dirty* has been used to convey *sullied*, *tainted*, *impure*, *corrupt*, *illicit*, *immoral*, etc.

The OED lists such nuances among its several meanings for *dirty*:

> 2a. Morally unclean or impure; ‘smutty’. Spec. *dirty book*, a
>   pornographic book; so *dirty bookshop*; *dirty joke, dirty story*, a
>   ‘smutty’ joke or story; *dirty weekend*, a sexually illicit weekend.
>   2b. That stains the honour of the persons engaged; dishonourably
>   sordid, base, mean, or corrupt; despicable.
>   ***1764***   Pulteney in Beatson Nav. & Mil. Mem. (1790) I. 26   *Some Ministers‥cannot do their dirty work without them*.

With that kind of heritage for the word *dirty*, it's not a long leap to apply the word *dirty* to *ill-gotten funds*.

As a side note, in addition to *dirty money*, the OED doesn't forget or neglect *dirty pool*, *dirty words*, *dirty tricks*, and *dirty old men*.

Comment: Your "not a long leap ... OED specifically ..." wording is misleading because the two quotes refer not to "ill-gotten funds" but instead to hazard pay, that is, extra reimbursement for certain jobs.

Comment: @jwpat7: True.  Astute observation.  Problem now fixed.

Comment: One notes that "dirty money" as illegal is also specially unpleasant because there is always the risk of being arrested for it.

Answer (score 8):

Probably date backs to Tyndale's translation of the Bible in the early 1500s, where *aiskhron kerdos* (shameful gains) was translated to *filthy lucre*.  The leap from filthy to dirty isn't far at all.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this derivation?

Comment: Other than Timothy 1:3?  There's this: http://www.cla.purdue.edu/english/theory/marxism/notes/lucre.html

Answer (score 6):

It's a metaphor, or rather a [Metaphor Theme](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Metaphors.pdf).

> ***CLEAN is GOOD ~ DIRTY is BAD***

Such a theme licenses reference to anything considered **"BAD"** by calling it **"DIRTY"** (somehow), and also licenses reference to anything considered **"GOOD"** by calling it **"CLEAN"** (somehow).

- *dirty money, filthy mouth, smutty talk, slimy morals, spotty record, ...*
- *clean living, well-scrubbed manners, fresh ideas, **laundered money,** ...*

Note that last one: *laundered money* refers to *dirty money* that's been *cleaned*, i.e, made officially acceptable by erasing its *dirty* origins. Rather like Vespasian's famous remark about the tax on urine, familiar to every school boy: *Pecunia non olet*.

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Mace, *Musick's Monument* (1676): "And now again methinks I see some of you tossing up your caps and crying aloud, "we will have an organ, and an organist too; 'tis but laying out a little dirty money." (Pt. 1, p. 12)

Comment: +1 This is an interesting find. A search of Early English Books Online yields [three texts](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo?sort=datea&ALLSELECTED=1&xc=1&g=eebogroup&type=simple&rgn=full+text&q1=dirty+money&singlegenre=All&c=eebo&c=eebo2&view=reslist&subview=short&start=1&size=25) of "dirty money" from the seventeenth century: the one you cite from 1676; _The False Count_, by Aphra Behn (1682); and _The Atheist_ by Thomas Otway (1684). It might be worthwhile to examine whether all three use "dirty money" in the same sense.