# Origin of the phrase "filthy rich"?

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the phrase "filthy rich"?

Comment: [origin of filthy rich](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/filthy-rich.html). Phrase Finder is good for this sort of thing.

Comment: Related: _[What is the origin of “dirty money”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/63606/5822)_

Answer (score 3):

As the link to [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/filthy-rich.html) above explains, this phrase evolved from the   phrase *filthy lucre* from the 1500s. Here's what [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lucre&searchmode=none) has on *lucre*:

> **lucre (n.)**
>
> late 14c., from L. *lucrum* "gain, advantage, profit; wealth, riches," from PIE root **lau*- "gain, profit" (cf. Gk. *apo-lanein* "to enjoy," Goth. *launs*, Ger. *lohn* "wages, reward," and possibly Skt. *lotam*, *lotram* "booty"). *Filthy lucre* (Tit. i:11) is Tyndale's rendering of Gk. *aischron kerdos*.

As Phrase Finder explains:

> Following on the the term "filthy lucre", money became known by the slang term "the filthy", and it isn't a great leap from there to the rich being called the "filthy rich". This was first used as a noun phrase meaning "rich people; who have become so by dishonourable means".

Phrase Finder claims a 1920s origin, but the two words can be found together in print from the early 1800s. [This](http://books.google.com/books?id=Gci8mvGaKpQC&dq=%22filthy+rich%22&q=filthy+rich#v=snippet&q=filthy%20rich&f=false), however, is the earliest example I can find of it being used as a set phrase rather than as a description of rich people who are physically dirty. Here's a clip from *A Certain Rich Man* by William Allen White, 1909 ([date check](http://books.google.com/books?id=Gci8mvGaKpQC&printsec=frontcover&vq=filthy%20rich#v=onepage&q=1909&f=false)):

[image: http://tinyurl.com/7whppee]

And a final point worth noting from Phrase Finder:

> As time went on the negative associations have softened somewhat. It has become to mean "extremely rich" rather than "dishonourably rich", although there may still be a trace of an unfavourable implication associated with it.

Comment: Great answer. At present day, "filthy rich" feels close to "so rich it's unfair."